# Problem with regular expression with 2 capture group, one is optional

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to write the correct regex to match the data below. I want to capture the "Focus+Terminal" and its optional parameter "NYET". How can I re-write my incorrect regex?

```
user:\/\/(.*)(?:=(.*+))?
```

I also tried and failed:

```
user:\/\/(.*)=?(?:(.*+))?
```

Sample Data

```
*   user://Focus+Terminal=NYET
*   user://Focus+Terminal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
user:\/\/(.*?)(?:=(.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UDQzJY/1).

*Details*:

- `user:\/\/` - a `user://` string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as **few** as possible
- `(?:=(.*))?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches a `=` and then captures into Group 2 any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you might use a negated character class excluding matching a newline or equals sign for the first capture group.

```
user:\/\/([^=\n]*)(?:=(.*))?
```

**Explanation**

- `user:\/\/` Match `user://`
- `([^=\n]*)` Capture **group 1**, match optional chars other than `=` or a newline
- `(?:=(.*))?` Optionally match `=` and capture the rest of the line in **group 2**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dTuBBQ/1)